# Python way of getting max of list containing integers and floats

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list like this in python

```
list = ['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3','1.4', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '3', '3.1', '3.2']
```

Can I get this result

```
['1', '1.4', '2', '2.2', '3', '3.2']
```

or

```
['1.4', '2.2', '3.2']
```

This is a task list in string format, and I need to get the last subtask under each parent.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what exactly those lists you posted signify. Im having trouble seeing where you got those exact lists

Comment: Will this list be always sorted?

Comment: These are task list, that I get in string format from db. For example 1 is a main level task, and 1.1 is a sub task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to define the comparing function:

```
def cmp_tasks(a,b):
    a = a.split('.')
    b = b.split('.')
    if len(a) == len(b):
        ret = cmp(int(a[0]),int(b[0]))
        if not ret:
            return cmp(int(a[1]),int(b[1]))
        return ret
    else:
        return cmp(int(a[0]),int(b[0]))
```

then:

**One Liner:**
You can do this in one liner:

```
>>> {int(float(i)):i for i in sorted(l,cmp=cmp_tasks)}.values()
['1.30', '2.2', '3.2']
```

**Detailed approach:**
or, more detailed: you first need to group the values according to their floored value:

```
l = ['1', '1.30', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3','1.4', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '3', '3.1', '3.2']
groups = {}
for i in l:
    groups.setdefault(int(float(i)),[]).append(i)
```

now

```
>>> groups
{1: ['1','1.30', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4'], 2: ['2', '2.1', '2.2'], 3: ['3', '3.1', '3.2']}
```

then you can take the maximum from each group:

```
>>> [sorted(g,cmp=cmp_tasks)[-1] for g in groups.values()]
['1.30', '2.2', '3.2']
```

**p.s.**
note that overriding `list` keyword is not a good idea, because you will not be able to use `list` afterwards

Comment: Although the question is a bit unclear, but from your logic 1.4 would come before 1.30, since `int(1.3) < int(1.4)`

Comment: I have been down voted for asking this question. Can anyone help

Comment: @Elisha both your methods are wrong since for the list `['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.30']`, both your solutions return `1.4` whereas `1.30` would be the last subtask.

Comment: are you sure 1.30 should be after 1.4 ? it is not clear from the question

Comment: How else can you represent a 1.30? You cant say it is same as 1.3. Thats the reason it has been given as string and not as plain integers. Also tasks are always numbers are 1, 1.1, 1.2...1.10, 1.11, 1.12. @user11283 please confirm

Comment: Oh I got busy implementing your answers. Sorry. 1.30 should be greater than 1.3

Comment: Is it possible to have something like `1.30.2`?

Comment: i fixed it.  however,it is less elegent :( (i assumed no 1.30.3 tasks)

Comment: Elisha, I implemented your latest change, it works perfect, thanks Hyades for pointing out my mistake. Now, its perfect. Elisha you may be interested in Dhtmlxgantt tool for which no python / django implementation exists. Although my work is over, may be somebody will need 1.30.3 tasks as well. If you can update it for second level subtasks, it will be great. Thanks all again.

Answer (score 2):

Simple itertools solution:

```
import itertools
l = ['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3','1.4', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '11', '11.1']
assert [list(group)[-1] for category, group in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x.split('.')[0])] == ['1.4', '2.2', '3.2', '11.1']
```

For different form of input data lambda function should be changed.

Comment: Try it out with this list `['1', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '11.2']`. Doing `x[0]` is wrong.

Comment: @hyades fixed. Anyway, I fell like providing extensive, precise test suite is an responsibility of person who ask. If you show only simplest input and simplest output you cannot expect generic solutions.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz For the answer.